# cmake xctest_add_bundle function explanation and examples

Tags: ios, cmake

In latest cmake version (v3.3.0), it is possible to create a XCTests bundle for MAC and IOS by using [xctest_add_bundle](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindXCTest.html). However the documentation on how to use this function is poor for me. Are there someone who can provide a sample to show how to use this function? Thanks.

For my application, I want to create a IOS APP along with XCTest. All should be done with cmake.

Answer (score 4):

You already have a link that describes about `xctest_add_bundle` and `xctest_add_test`. So i just give you an example source code in below.

I have found an example code from cmake project. It includes not only `CMakelist.txt` file but also sample test codes. Please note that example.

https://cmake.org/gitweb?p=cmake.git;a=tree;f=Tests/XCTest;h=e0b3009744e263fcc81009471c34049a46e8bc7a;hb=HEAD

```
enable_testing()

find_package(XCTest REQUIRED)

# Framework

add_library(FrameworkExample SHARED
  ${some_source_codes}
  FrameworkExample/Info.plist)

target_include_directories(FrameworkExample PUBLIC .)

set_target_properties(FrameworkExample PROPERTIES
  FRAMEWORK TRUE      # in my experience, this property should be TRUE
  VERSION "1.0.0"
  SOVERSION "1.0.0"
  FRAMEWORK_VERSION "A"
  MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FrameworkExample/Info.plist
  PUBLIC_HEADER FrameworkExample/FrameworkExample.h)

# XCTest for Framework

xctest_add_bundle(FrameworkExampleTests FrameworkExample
  FrameworkExampleTests/FrameworkExampleTests.m
  FrameworkExampleTests/Info.plist)

set_target_properties(FrameworkExampleTests PROPERTIES
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FrameworkExampleTests/Info.plist
  )

xctest_add_test(XCTest.FrameworkExample FrameworkExampleTests)
```

Comment: This got me 90% of the way there. Also had to make sure `ARCHS` was set to `x86_64` and the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` (where the XCTest framework lives)  was pointing to the one for the iphone simulator.

Comment: Thanks @rstackhouse for the last 10%. This is a cmake [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19809) that tries to force the framework search path. What worked for me was to reset this property (inherited values should be retained):
`set_target_properties(FrameworkExampleTests PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS "")`