# How to have Info.plist bundled in a MacOSX application with CMake?

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake, plist

I'm developing an application accessing the camera. The project is written in C++ and I'm using CMake to package it.

To deploy the project in a Mac, I use the command below, and then open the project in Xcode:

```
cmake -G Xcode ../src
```

It worked fine until last update, when it started complaining about:

```
[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access 
privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's 
Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with 
a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

So I created a new Info.plist file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="0.9">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
        <string>This app requires to access your camera 
            to retrieve images and perform the demo</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

My question is: What should I add in CMakeLists.txt to take this file and put it in the proper place? And... is it possible that `cmake -G Xcode` would include it correctly in the Xcode project?

**EDIT** Following recommendations, I tried this:

```
  # Compile files:
  add_executable(fpv 
    main.cpp

    files.cpp
    files.hpp

    more-files.cpp
    more-files.hpp
 )

# Link files:
target_link_libraries(fpv
   fpv-lib
   ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES}  
   ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

# Lets bundle it:
set_target_properties(fpv PROPERTIES
  FRAMEWORK TRUE
  FRAMEWORK_VERSION C
  MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.cmake.dynamicFramework
  MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist
  # "current version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
  VERSION 16.4.0
  # "compatibility version" in semantic format in Mach-O binary file
  SOVERSION 1.0.0
  # XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY "Jean-Michel Gonet"
)
```

**EDIT** To be sure the Info.plist is correct I manually added it in the Xcode project:

- Added the Info.plist as a source in the project.
- Selected it in the project navigator.
- Renamed it (!) to Info.cpp, so that I can include it in the target.
- Renamed it back to Info.plist.
- Launched the application, that asked my permission for accessing the camera.

And then it worked.

But I would still like to have project configuration in CMake.

Comment: Try using MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST , [sample1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262485/cmake-xctest-add-bundle-function-explanation-and-examples), [sample2](http://www.reeonce.be/notes/cmake/ios-framework/)

Comment: @Raviprakash Thanks for the info. However, I'm still lost. I know that I need to cook something up with MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST, FRAMEWORK and CMake, but I haven't found so far a complete example. Only people that look far better informed than me, speaking about details.

Comment: There's a full test for creating a Mac OS X framework at https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/Framework/CMakeLists.txt from the CMake guys. Maybe that helps further.

Comment: @vre Thanks, this is an official example of using FRAMEWORK. However, my goal is to have the Info.plist placed in the right place for Xcode to get it without trying to compile it. This example doesn't contain or mention any *.plist file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Official Cmake's documentation (see [cmake-properties-7](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html)) mentions 2 families of *MACOSX* target properties:

- `FRAMEWORK`, `FRAMEWORK_VERSION` and `MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_INFO_PLIST`
- `MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST` and `MACOSX_BUNDLE`

Now, the inclusion of `Info.plist` is managed by the latter *Bundle* family.

To have a complete example, let say your application is called *fpv*, and your directory structure is:

```
/src   <-- Root folder
 /lib  <-- There you may add sources for your application's library
      CMakeLists.txt <-- Library has its own configuration
      more-files.cpp
      lots-of-files.cpp
      etc.cpp
      ...
 /app  <-- This is where executable resides
      CMakeLists.txt <-- This is where you need to configure the bundle
      Info.plist    <-- I've placed the plist file just besides.
      main.cpp
      second.cpp
      more.cpp
```

This is how your application's `CMakeLists.txt` could look like:

```
# src/app
project( fpv )

# GTKMM has to be linked/included via pkg_config:
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0) # Defines variables GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS, GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS and GTKMM_LIBRARIES.
link_directories( ${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

# OpenCV can be linked as usual:
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

# Compile files:
add_executable(fpv 
    main.cpp

    main-window.cpp
    main-window.hpp

    auto-viseur.cpp
    auto-viseur.hpp
 )

# Link files:
target_link_libraries(fpv
   fpv-lib
   ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES}  
   ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

# Lets bundle it:
set_target_properties(fpv PROPERTIES
  MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
  MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist
)
```

To build the XCode project, create a `xcode` folder besides the main `src` folder:

```
mkdir xcode
cd xcode
cmake -G Xcode ../src
```

Now you can open it as a project from *Xcode*. To execute in debug mode:

- Select your application's target (top left-ish side, by default it is set to ALL_BUILD). You'll notice that the icon has changed to a stylized A.
- Run it.
- If all went well, you should be requested to allow your application to access camera.
- Also, you should see the `Info.plist` file as a resource